# Using flexbox, how can implement columns of equal width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to create a layout that has three columns of equal width.

I would also like the columns to remain of equal width if the containing row expands in width.

I would also like the columns to constrain the width of their content. To be precise, I want each column to contain it's content, and not stretch in response. So paragraphs should wrap and images with dimensions wider than the column should not stretch the column.

How can this be done with flexbox?

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your HTML and CSS to the question.

Comment: There is no real need to involve flexbox in this question based solely on the criteria provided.  All you need is width: 33%.  But in the spirit of the question, [here is a Fiddle with a flex container.](https://jsfiddle.net/vm8odgkr/1/)